# how to properly close a modal through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-add-menu").click(function(){
  $('.pace-done').addClass('no-pad');
  $("#myModalAddApplet").modal('hide');
});

});
```

The issue with this is that it successfully hides the modal `#myModalAddApplet`but the new modal it opens are long and the scroll bar is not working with the modal after this happens, i have tried debugging it myself and the issue is with the line `$("#myModalAddApplet").modal('hide');` because if I comment out that line then the scroll bar works fine.

Anyone here who can teach me how to properly close or hide my modal...

PS. `.btn-add-menu` opens another modal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the jQuery code (it is correct), but in the fact that you're forcing jQuery/Bootstrap to close & open the dialog at the same time. You really shouldn't bind two actions (both declarative and imperative, in particular) on a single button - this is an antipattern & is overall a bad programming habit.

Remove the declarative dialog call from the `.btn-add-menu`, move it to the jQuery action and wrap in a timeout to allow previous dialog action to complete:

```
$(".btn-add-menu").click(function(){
    $('.pace-done').addClass('no-pad');
    $("#myModalAddApplet").modal('hide');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#otherApplet").modal('show');
    },
    500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I have to change a lot of codes if that is the reason why it didn't work properly...